# How to convert a string representation of an array of objects to an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an string of a array of objects that looks like this

```
"[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]"
```

I whant to convert to a array of objects like this:

```
[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
```

can someone help with that?

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]".replaceAll("'",'"')))
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI I manage to accomplish that replacing the single quotes with doubles quotes

> '

replace for

> "

```
string = taxSettings?.replace(/'/g, '"');
array = JSON.parse(string);
```